# Determine if the series $a_n = \frac{n!}{(1+n)^n}x^n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Determine if  the series $$a_n = \frac{n!}{(1+n)^n}x^n$$ converges

It is smaller than $$b_n=\left(\frac{n}{1+n}\right)^n x^n$$ For $0<x<1$
If I use cauchy root test and comparison test with bn, right hand side goes to zero hence series converges but I can't think how to deal with other cases ,for instance for $x>1$ rhs diverges so you can't use that

If I use D'Alembert's Ratio test,
it is easy to see limit of the ratio goes to $$|x|\frac1e$$
so case of only where $x=e$ is left but I dont know how to do that.
Can someone help me?

Comment: sequence or series? I don't see a summation sign, so...

Comment: Series (I have written series in the question to avoid confusion :p)

Comment: You have not written a summation sign in the question, which will continue to promote ambiguity until you out the summations signs there, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you are asking about the radius of convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n!}{(1+n)^{n}}x^{n}$$

To check for convergence, we can apply the ratio test,

\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right|= \left|\frac{\frac{(n+1)!x^{n+1}}{(1+(n+1))^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!x^{n}}{(1+n)^{n}}} \right|=|x| \left|\frac{(1+n)(1+n)^{n}n!}{(2+n)^{n}(2+n)n!} \right|\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}|x|e^{\frac{-n-1}{n+2}}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}e^{-1}|x|
\end{align*}

Hence convergence absolutely if $|x|<e$ by the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#:%7E:text=The%20ratio%20test%20states%20that,series%20that%20satisfy%20this%20case.)
and divergence for $|x|>e$. If $|x|=e$ so $x=-e$ or $x=e$ we need to test these values of $x$ separately.

- With $x=-e$ we have $ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{n!}{(n+1)^{n}} (-e)^{n}$ diverges.
- With $x=e$ we have  $ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{n!}{(n+1)^{n}} (e)^{n}$ diverges.

[Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) give: $n!\underset{+\infty}{\sim}\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^{n}$ then $$\frac{n!e^{n}}{(n+1)^{n}} \underset{+\infty}{\sim} \sqrt{2\pi n}\left( \frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\frac{e^{n}}{(n+1)^{n}}=\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n^{n}}{(n+1)^{n}}$$ Hence,
$$ \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n^{n}}{(n+1)^{n}}}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{n^{n}}{(n+1)^{n}}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi }}{e}$$
Since $0<\frac{\sqrt{2\pi }}{e}<+\infty$ and the series of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\sqrt{n}$ diverges so $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{n!e^{n}}{(n+1)^{n}}$ diverges by [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Comment: Yes I had already thought till this stage in the solution. Can you tell how are you getting divergence in x=e case. That's the part I couldn't figure out. Thanks

Comment: @simpleman5 I've add more details. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: I'm so sorry we haven't been taught stirlings formula and can't use it . Do you know some other way to get around this? Thank you

Comment: @simpleman5 Well, so notice that $e^{x}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{j}}{j!}$ for all $x$ so $n!e^{n}\geqslant \sum_{j=0}^{n}n! \frac{e^{j}}{j!}\geqslant \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}n^{k}=(n+1)$. Therefore for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\frac{n!e^{n}}{(n+1)^{n}}>1$ so the terms don't even approach zero. Hence $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}  \frac{n!e^{n}}{(n+1)^{n}}$ diverges. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Yep Thanks! Sorry for the trouble lol

Comment: You're welcome. If you're according to the answer you can click the bottom check in the asnwer.